# How can I have two different styles in the same page

Tags: php, html, css, styles

I have inside the loop two **DIV** and I need put a style to one and another to the other **DIV**.

I do not know if I can do it with PHP, JS or CSS. This is my code:

-- the styles (this styles are in the same page, because I have a general style that I include) --

```
    <?php
    $style_1 = '<style>
        .content .postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { margin-bottom: 7px;  }
        .content .postcontent-0 .layout-item-1 { border-spacing: 10px 0px; border-collapse: separate;  }
        .content .postcontent-0 .layout-item-2 { border-top-style:solid; background: #ffffff;  }

    </style>';

    $style_2 = '<style>
        .content .postcontent-0 .layout-item-0 { color: #083752; background: ;  border-collapse: separate;  }
        .content .postcontent-0 .layout-item-1 { color: #083752;  }
        .content .postcontent-0 .layout-item-2 { border-style:Double; border-radius: 15px;  }
        .content .postcontent-0 .layout-item-3 { padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;  }
          </style>';
    ?>
```

-- the view

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++) { ?>
<!--Here begin the STYLE_1-->
    <div class="content-layout-wrapper layout-item-0">
       <div class="content-layout layout-item-1">
         <div class="content-layout-row">
           <div class="layout-cell layout-item-2">
             <p> Text #1 </p>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <!--Here END the STYLE_1-->

    <!--Here begin the STYLE_2-->
     <div class="postcontent postcontent-0 clearfix">
        <div class="content-layout-wrapper layout-item-0">
            <div class="content-layout-row">
                 <div class="content-layout layout-item-1">
                       Text #2
                 </div>
                 <div class="layout-cell layout-item-2" >
                     <p>
                      Text #3
                    </p>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-layout">
             <div class="content-layout-row">
                  <div class="content-layout layout-item-3">
                      <p>Text # 4</p>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<!--Here END the STYLE_2-->

  <?php   } // for i  ?>
```

Comment: Hi, You shoud use id or classname to assign css to the divs.

Comment: And why you are doing CSS in this way? you should use separate file for CSS code. Don't do it in JS

Comment: that is the problem, all the div have diferents styles and the same name

Comment: So what about giving dynamic id's using loop and using those id's you should assign css in the same way

Comment: @I always do it in this way.

Comment: Then you can use the nth-child selector.https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: let me explaine better, I am redesigning a web page, i am put in with server language, database, etc. and I have to follow the same design that the page have now.  As the site is in html has a page to show each link, and each page have a general style and different styles but the same class names. like <div class="content-layout layout-item-1">

Comment: how can i make a dynamic id's using loop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different class name for two separate div but if you want to use this without change the existing class name then use inline css.Try this code:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++) { ?>
<!--Here begin the STYLE_1-->
    <div class="content-layout-wrapper layout-item-0" style="margin-bottom: 7px;">
       <div class="content-layout layout-item-1" style=" border-spacing: 10px 0px; border-collapse: separate; ">
         <div class="content-layout-row">
           <div class="layout-cell layout-item-2" style="border-top-style:solid; background: #ffffff;">
             <p> Text #1 </p>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <!--Here END the STYLE_1-->

    <!--Here begin the STYLE_2-->
     <div class="postcontent postcontent-0 clearfix">
        <div class="content-layout-wrapper layout-item-0" style="color: #083752; background: ;  border-collapse: separate;">
            <div class="content-layout-row">
                 <div class="content-layout layout-item-1" style="color: #083752;">
                       Text #2
                 </div>
                 <div class="layout-cell layout-item-2" style"border-style:Double; border-radius: 15px;">
                     <p>
                      Text #3
                    </p>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-layout">
             <div class="content-layout-row">
                  <div class="content-layout layout-item-3" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                      <p>Text # 4</p>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<!--Here END the STYLE_2-->

  <?php   } // for i  ?>
```

Comment: Maybe this is a solution, but if i will have to change the style I have to change manually for all the pages. But, yes, maybe is the solution. Thanks for answer

Comment: Wellcome, I have mentioned that in my answer you can use different class name because inline CSS in HTML not  a good practice.

Comment: if you think that is the right answer for your asking a question then please approve my answer in StackOverflow procedural way.

Comment: I follow your first suggestio n,I change the class names, I think I just block me